# Alter column value directly after creation (within a single stored procedure)

Tags: sql

I need to add an additional column to an existing table, and afterwards insert the appropriate column values for the existing records. I need to do this within a single stored procedure.

So far I have the following (SQL Management studio reports that it cannot find the new column in order to add the values to the existing records):

```
    BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE tbl1
    ADD col_add int

    UPDATE tbl1
    SET [col_add]='value'
    WHERE col_pk = 1
    END
```

I have tried adding a "GO" keyword between the ALTER and UPDATE statements, but then it reports a syntax error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You must commit your 'alter table' and then do your update, and don't forget to commit your update too :

```
 BEGIN
  BEGIN TRAN
    ALTER TABLE tbl1
    ADD col_add date
COMMIT;
   BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE tbl1
    SET [col_add]='value'
    WHERE col_pk = 1
COMMIT;
    END
```

Comment: This is half way there, but you need to begin your transactions with `BEGIN TRAN` before you can commit them

Comment: Is that really needed if you make commit one after another? Maybe if you make 'alter', 'update' and then would commit, you have to add transaction, but I don't think if you make 'alter' 'commit' 'update' 'commit', you need transaction. maybe I'm wrong but...

Comment: Yes it is needed, test it. The procedure will compile without `BEGIN TRAN`, but will come up with an error when run. There is a test script [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ed4a/1), which won't run because of permissions on SQL Fiddle, but you can try it on your DB. If you uncomment the `BEGIN TRAN` lines you will see the procedure runs with no error (if run once).

Comment: Ok. I edited response with your comments.

Answer (score 2):

The table name error occurs during parsing.  In SSMS, `go` works because it separates batches.  But a stored procedure is always a single batch.

You can use `exec` or `sp_executesql` to force a new round of parsing inside a stored procedure:

```
exec ('UPDATE tbl1 SET [col_add]='value' WHERE col_pk = 1')
```